# Prevent animated div from creating overflow

Tags: html, css, animation, overflow

I am creating a website that uses animated divs to create a nice background but when they are animated it creates overflow and this makes the website very unresponsive especially on smaller screens.
How can I prevent an animated div from creating overflow on the x and y axis?
It is just used as a background element but it creates overflow on both the x and y axis when it rotates

```html
<body>
    <div class="animated-div"></div>
    <div>
        <!-- Rest of the website goes here -->
    </div>
</body>
```

I animated it using the basic CSS keyframes like this:

```css
.animated-div {
    height: 34vmax;
    aspect-ratio: 1;
    position: absolute;
    left: 70%; /* Used to position the div*/
    top: 60%; /* Used to position the div*/
    translate: -50% -50%;
    animation: rotate 10s infinite;
}
@keyframes rotate {
    from {
      rotate: 0deg;
    }
    
    50% {
      scale: 1 1.3;
    }
    
    to {
      rotate: 360deg;
    }
}
```

Also, I cannot use `overflow:hidden;` as it the website is scrollable.

Comment: Please post enough code so it can reproduced.

Comment: @JasonBruce there

Answer (score 0):

try `.animated-div{position: fixed;}` in the CSS file and rearrange your top and left, compare to the fixed position

Comment: Thank you, but while this does remove the overflow, it also prevents the divs from scrolling all together, do you know how I could fix that?

Comment: you just changed absolute to fixed right?
need more details about your code(enough code)

Comment: Yes, all I did was change from absolute to fix, the divs don't scroll anymore but everything else on the website scrolls fine (and this *did* fix the overflow)